# if body class hasclass add js if not add this js

Tags: php, javascript, if-statement

Anybody can tell me what is wrong here? I have a conflict with

`ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js`,

So that's why I need `noconflict` to true,but if I assigned it to all pages my `slidingpanels` doesn't work.I really need to have the sliding panel script on pages that isn't `virtuemart` help

```
<?php
    if ($("body").hasClass("option-com-virtuemart")) {
       addScript("noflict.js");}
      else {
      addScript("slidingpanel.js");} 
    ?>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

`if ($("body").hasClass("option-com-virtuemart")) {` appears to be JavaScript (using the jQuery library). It isn't PHP so it can't run inside a `<?php ?>` block.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I don't really know much about php and javascript.. i get confuse with both of them,, Can you help me how should this things be?

I need a code that if a body has a class of option-com-virtuemart, a noflict.js should be added, if not then slidingpanel.js will be added..

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You have written `jQuery` code inside the `PHP` block, free from that and try again.